# Case insensitive variables in the Maximize function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The `Maximize` function behaved very weirdly when I combined variable names with lower and upper cases. I created a minimum working example for reproducibility.

The following is an optimization function calling the `Maximize` function with two variables: `X` and `x`.

```
Maximize[{Abs[X - x], Abs[2 X - x] <= 1.0 && -128.0 <= x <= 127.0 && x \[Element] Integers}, {X, x}]
```

The incorrect output is:

```
{20., {X -> -19., x -> -39}}
```

After spending a couple of hours debugging the issue, I tried changing `x` to `y`. The revised code is:

```
Maximize[{Abs[X - y], Abs[2 X - y] <= 1.0 && -128.0 <= y <= 127.0 && y \[Element] Integers}, {X, y}]
```

This time the output is as expected and is:

```
{64.5, {X -> -63.5, y -> -128}}
```

Am I missing something here or is this the expected behavior? I was surprised because most programming languages have case sensitive variables and this behavior was very unexpected for me.

Comment: This works as expected `Maximize[{Abs[X - x], Abs[2 X - x] <= 1 && -128 <= x <= 127}, {X, x}]`

Comment: But then this doesn't work `Maximize[{Abs[X - s], 
  Abs[2 X - s] <= 1.0 && -128.0 <= s <= 127.0 && 
   s \[Element] Integers}, {X, s}]`

Comment: From your first comment, `Maximize` does recognize case sensitive variables. From your second comment, the result is unexpected. The output apparently is dependent on the name of the second variable, which is quite weird.

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: `x \[Element] Integers` may cause the problem?Because this works `Maximize[{Abs[X - s], 
  Abs[2 X - s] <= 1.0 && -128.0 <= s <= 127.0}, {X, s}]` But then why this works `Maximize[{Abs[L - s], 
  Abs[2 L - s] <= 1.0 && -128.0 <= s <= 127.0 && 
   s \[Element] Integers}, {L, s}]`

Comment: I do not have any understanding of this unexpected behavior. I am waiting for someone to give some insights. This code is part of a bigger program and I do not know which calls to the `Maximize` function to trust.